# Input in BigQuery - Python

Tags: python, input, google-bigquery

I am working in python with a bigquery library. I already have the connection to the bigquery base that I need:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'path/to/file.json')

project_id = 'my-bq'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
```

However, now I need to input data into this bigquery, but I have no idea how to do this, could someone help me?

Comment: Typo error, first character is missing in first line.

Comment: Thank you, adjusted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a JSON (`read_json`) or CSV (`read_csv`) file using Pandas data-frame and load data into BigQuery.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path/to/file.json')
project_id = 'my-bq'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
tableRef = client.dataset("dataset-name").table("table-name")

dataFrame = pd.read_json("file-name.json")

jobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
jobConfig.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    
bigqueryJob = bigqueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(dataFrame, tableRef, job_config=jobConfig)
bigqueryJob.result()
```

Comment: a doubt, does this include the new data, or replace the existing data with the new data?

Comment: You can choose Write Disposition as WRITE_APPEND or WRITE_TRUNCATE. Edited code snippet with example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try

Comment: Please consider voting up the answer if it helped !